# Why does the typescript compiler not find the property create on Injector in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an angular application. And I am trying to create unit tests where I am mocking http responses. I am following this tutorial (https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend). For some reason the typescript compiler keeps throwing this error when I call Injector.create();

Unit test

```
  it("Should return an geographicLocation:GeographicLocation[]", fakeAsync(()=>{
    let text:string;
    let injector = Injector.create([
      {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass:MockBackend},
      {provide: RequestOptions, useClass:BaseRequestOptions },
      Http
    ]);

  }));
```

[image: error]

My package.json looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "inloggning",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.15",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

I realize that some of the @angular dependencies are not updated. But I tried updating them, and still got the same error. What could be causing this?

Comment: Where do you import Injector from ?

Comment: import {Injector, Injectable} from '@angular/core'; As is done in the example.

Comment: I just realized that angular5 has released, might I have to update to angular5 to get this to work?